# Toolbar popupTheme isn't white

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set up my toolbar with white text and white dots menu, white popup and black text inside the popup, and trasparent background.
I'm also get it, but the popup is black and the test inside it's white. How could I change it?

That's my code:

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.bacci.testapp.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Info"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

mainActivity.xml

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        >
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And the MainActivity class:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("RateMe.ai");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Actually the toolbar is trasparent, the text and the menu icon is white, but the popup where I have the option is black with white text. I want it white with black text.
Here a picture of the actual situation

[image]

Comment: I think the popupTheme is only applied when using the `app:popupTheme` XML property, not `android:popupTheme`. Telle me if that fixed the problem.

Comment: @ThibaultSeisel yes, You were right! In another question a guy answered by saying to use android:popupTheme, but it wasn't. Thank you so much man!